# How to shift image to left (or right)?

Tags: java, image, awt, bufferedimage

I'm writing an Java program that do some stuffs with images.

Now I need to shift my image to left `n pixels`. I can clip the image with a shape using `Graphics.setClip(Shape)` functions.But I cannot move it to left alignment.

[EDIT] Sorry for the lack of information of the above question.

I have an image, and draw it on a canvas like this:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}
```

I need to shift my image to left `n pixels` on my canvas (so I can draw something new to the place on right side after shifting).

[image: image before shifting]
[image]

This is an example. Image 1 is the original one, the second is the one after shifting.
Please tell me how can I do that.

Thanks all!

Comment: how do you draw image? using drawImage()?

Comment: one line of code says more than a hundred words... Post your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use [`BufferedImage.getSubimage(x,y,w,h)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

class ImageCrop {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/enifS.jpg");
        final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
        int x = 43;
        final Image crop = image.getSubimage(x, 0, image.getWidth()-x, image.getHeight());
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));

                gui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
                gui.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(crop)), BorderLayout.LINE_END);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Of course, a simpler way is to change:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}
```

To:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(image, -43, 0, this);
}
```